# difference of template structure: Wordpress traditional themes vs FSE-(full site editing) themes

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to find out how the templates of traditional themes are different form FSE-(full site editing) themes;

can we say so: A template of a traditional theme would have this structure:

```
├── theme-name
│ ├── template-parts
│ │ ├── content.php
│ ├── templates
│ │ ├── template-cover.php
│ │ ├── template-full-width.php
│ ├── index.php
│ ├── style.css
```

and besides this a FSE theme would have this structure:

```
├── theme-name
│ ├── block-template-parts
│ │ ├── header.html
│ │ ├── footer.html
│ ├── block-templates
│ │ ├── index.html
│ ├── index.php
│ ├── style.css
```

in other words, the structure of a very simple block theme is structured like so:

```
theme
|__ style.css
|__ theme.json
|__ functions.php
|__ block-templates
    |__ index.html
    |__ single.html
    |__ archive.html
    |__ ...
|__ block-template-parts
    |__ header.html
    |__ footer.html
    |__ sidebar.html
    |__ ...
```

To sume up: The difference with existing WordPress themes is that the different templates in the template hierarchy, and template parts, are block templates instead of php files. In addition, this example includes a theme.json file for some styles.

Question: is this the whole description?

Well how can we see the differences between the both types
love to hear from you.

Answer (score 1):

That is pretty much the whole description, yes. FSE themes follow the same template hierarchy.

- The folder names have been updated to "templates" and "parts".
- If WordPress can not find the corresponding HTML template according to the template hierarchy, it will look for a PHP version of that file as a fallback.

Comment: many thanks for the reply. Awesome - happy to hear from you. I love Gutenberg - its so awesome. BTW: keep up your great work - it rocks ;)